# ¿Como realizar conexión de una programa de escritorio a una BD SQL alojada en otra PC dentro de la RED?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo una gran incertidumbre sobre como lograr que un programa de escritorio que desarrolle pueda conectarse a una base de datos sql.

En mi PC tengo creada una base de datos en SQL 2017 que es alimentada a través del sistema de escritorio que desarrolle con C#.

Lo que quiero hacer es instalar ese sistema en dos computadoras mas y que mi equipo funcione como servidor, es decir que el sistema una vez instalado en otros equipos puedan acceder de alguna forma a la BD pero no he encontrado manera para hacerlo.

No se si deba realizar por ejemplo algún cambio a mi cadena de conexión

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=LG-K40;database=catalogos;Trusted_Connection=True;")
```

O si debo hacer algunas configuraciones a mi equipo o a los que funcionaran como Clientes

Answer (score 0):

Para que se conecten los clientes remotamente a tu "servidor" donde esta la base de datos, tiene que verificar que el firewall permita la conexión y en el string de conexión te recomiendo usar la ip de la maquina:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=IP;database=catalogos;Trusted_Connection=True;")
```

Para verificar que tiene reglas hacia tu servidor puedes probar con telnet:

```
telnet ip puerto-bd
```

Si conecta a travez de telnet no deberia haber ningun problema para conectarte remotamente